# Weirdness of itertools.groupby in Python when realizing the groupby result early

Tags: python, python-itertools

First, apologies for my poor description of the problem. I can't find a better one.

I found that applying list to an itertools.groupby result will destroy the result. See code:

```
import itertools
import operator

log = '''\
hello world
hello there
hi guys
hi girls'''.split('\n')

data = [line.split() for line in log]

grouped = list(itertools.groupby(data, operator.itemgetter(0)))

for key, group in grouped:
    print key, group, list(group)

print '-'*80

grouped = itertools.groupby(data, operator.itemgetter(0))

for key, group in grouped:
    print key, group, list(group)
```

The result is:

```
hello <itertools._grouper object at 0x01A86050> []
hi <itertools._grouper object at 0x01A86070> [['hi', 'girls']]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<itertools.groupby object at 0x01A824E0>
hello <itertools._grouper object at 0x01A860B0> [['hello', 'world'], ['hello', 'there']]
hi <itertools._grouper object at 0x01A7DFF0> [['hi', 'guys'], ['hi', 'girls']]
```

Probably this is related to the internal working of the groupby function. Nevertheless it surprised me today.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [documented](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

> The returned group is itself an iterator that shares the underlying iterable with `groupby()`. Because the source is shared, when the `groupby()` object is advanced, the previous group is no longer visible.

When you do `list(groupby(...))`, you advance the groupby object all the way to the end, this losing all groups except the last.  If you need to save the groups, do as shown in the documentation and save each one while iterating over the groupby object.

Answer (score 2):

The example in the documentation is not as nice as:

```
list((key, list(group)) for key, group in itertools.groupby(...))
```

in turning the iterator into a list of tuples of keys and lists of groups: `[(key,[group])]` if that is what is desired.

Comment: If you want to do that, no need to use `list`, just use a list comprehension directly: `[(key, list(group)) for key, group in itertools.groupby(...)]`

Comment: @BrenBarn One could but that doesn't have the same behavior on both Python 2 and 3 where on Python 2 it leaks variables that generator expressions don't. This was fixed in Python 3 but in doing so the speed increase of using `[]` over `list()` was removed. And also one couldn't simply replace `list` with `dict` and get `{key:[group]}` instead.